# Main section overlapping footer

Tags: footer, overlapping

http://tinypic.com/r/hrbfic/5

Hello i got problem with my footer. The main section is overlapping my footer. Main section position is relative and footer position is absolute. I dont want my footer position to be fixed. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
html
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px none;
outline: 0px none;
font-size: 100%;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;



}

body
{
background-image: url('/images/tlo.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Arial;
font-size: 100%;
height:100%;
}


h1, .leg
{
font-size:12px;
color: orange;
text-align:center;
}

h2
{
font-size:12px;
color: orange;
text-align:left;
}

p     
{   
    color: white;   
    margin-top: .5em;  
    font-size: .75em;  
    padding-left:1%;  
    padding-right:1%;   
} 

.right  
{   
    color: white;   
    margin-top: .5em;  
    font-size: .75em;  
    padding-left:5%;  
    text-align:right;

    font-style:oblique;
}   

#top
{
padding-top:60px;
padding-bottom:20px;
height:auto;
width:1024px;
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0px auto;

}

nav
{
border-width: thin;
border:1px solid gray;
background-image: url('/images/tweed.png');
}
header
{
background-image: url('/images/tlo.png');
}


#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5
{
position:relative;
padding:30px;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
width:1024px;
background-image: url('/images/podklad.png');
border-width: thin;
border:1px solid gray;
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;

}



#menu
{
position:relative;
text-align: center;
height:120px;
width:100%;
margin: 0px auto;
border:0px;
font-size:0px;
background-image:url('/images/podklad.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}

#stopka
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
height:100px;
background-image:url('/images/podklad.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
margin: 0px auto;
}
ul.lista
{
text-align:center; 
list-style-type:none; 
margin:0; 
}
ul#jezyki
    {
    list-style: circle;  
    color: white;   
    margin-top: .5em;  
    font-size: .75em; 
    text-align:center;
    }
li.lista
{
display:inline;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.linki
{
font-size:14px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}

.clear {
display:block;
float:none;
clear:both;
height:0px;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}
```

```
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Damian Pruszynski Webdesign</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Habibi' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sliding_effect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mojefunkcje.js"></script>

<meta name="keywords" content="Damian Pruszynski, webdesign, bialystok webdesign, strony www, programowanie bialystok, pisanie stron www, pisanie stron www bialystok, robienie stron www bialystok, robienie stron" />
        <meta name="description" content="Damian Pruszynski - strona domowa, programowanie i webdesign. Programowanie stron www - HTML5 CSS3 jQuery. Skrypty PHP5 Javascript. Bannery oraz grafiki promujące. Łatwo tanio i przyjemnie."/>
        <meta name="author" content="Damian Pruszyński"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<a href="//plus.google.com/115218512345333970807?prsrc=3" rel="publisher" target="_top"></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/114098387423288903496?rel=author"></a>
<div id="toppodklad"></div>
<div id="top">
<img src="/images/logotop.png" alt="logo glowne" />
</div>

</header>
<nav>
<div id="menu">
<ul class="lista">

<li class="lista"><a id="pokaz1" href="index.php" ><img src="/images/pasek_01.png" alt=" "  /></a></li>
<li class="lista"><a id="pokaz2" href="autor.php" ><img src="/images/pasek_02.png" alt=" "  /></a></li>
<li class="lista"><a id="pokaz3" href="projekty.php" ><img src="/images/pasek_03.png" alt=" "  /></a></li>
<li class="lista"><a id="pokaz4" href="kontakt.php" ><img src="/images/pasek_04.png" alt=" "  /></a></li>
<li class="lista"><a id="pokaz5" href="logowanie.php" ><img src="/images/pasek_05.png" alt=" "  /></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</nav>
<div id="container">
<div id="div1">
<?php
        include("newsy.php");
?>
</div>

</div>
<div id="stopka"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `(clear:both;)` in css hope it helps